# Can you update the string.xml resource file while the app is running?

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile-application

I am making a basic todo list app in android studio for practice. I want users to be able to type a description of a task they need to do in an EditText view. The program should store that task in the strings.xml file, and append that new task to a list so it can be displayed using a recyclerview.

The problem I am having is that my TODOItem class takes in an int (representing the StringResourceID). When I take in a value from the EditText view it is a String. How can I make a string into a StringResourceID that is stored in the string.xml file when the user presses a button?
[Landing page with list of tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqbIw.png)
[When user presses add, title of task should add to strings.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lj0c.png)

Comment: The strings.xml file is not editable. Maybe its not even there.

Comment: You cannot manipulate the string.xm resource file dynamically. Check this if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37496454/is-it-possible-to-update-string-xml-file-at-run-time-in-android

Comment: Try using a database like SQLite to store your data rather than strings.xml, which i dont think cant be edited